# To search a value and then delete object containing it from an array of objects?

Tags: c++, vector, find

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A
{
      public :
      void getData(vector< A > &);
      void putData(vector< A > &);

      private :
              int x;
              char name[90];
};
vector< A > v;

void A :: getData(vector< A > &Aref)
{
     cout << "id = ";
     cin >> x;
     cout << "\nname = ";
     cin >> name;

}

void A :: putData(vector< A > &Aref)
{
     cout << "size of vector is " << Aref.size()  << endl;
     for(int i=0; i < Aref.size(); i++)
     cout << Aref[i].x << " : " << Aref[i].name << endl;

     cin.ignore(numeric_limits< streamsize >::max(), '\n'); 
     cin.get();
}


int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    v.push_back(A());
    v[0].getData(v);
    v[0].putData(v);
    }
    vector< A >::iterator beg = v.begin(), en = v.end();
    //v.erase( find(beg, en, v[1]) ); ----------------> DOESN'T WORK
    return 0;   
}
```

I have used this
`v.erase( find(beg, en, v[1]) );` (second to last line just before `return 0;`)
to search and delete an object from the array `vector< A > v;` (A is the name of class).
`beg` and `en` are iterators pointing to begining and end.

Does find accept the object as its 3rd argument? If not, what ways can I follow to delete an object? In fact I want to **search** the particular attribute(such as id, name) **value** from the array of objects and then **delete that object**.

Please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice:

1. Simplify. You could have reproduced this error with much smaller code.

   Post the error messages. This code does not throw an error, it fails to compile.

   Read the error messages. You class `A` lacks an equality operator (`operator==`), so `find` can't act on it-- how can it know when it's found a match?

   Test the details as you add them. You should have caught `v[0].putData(v)` before you even attempted `find`.

   Learn to do things by hand before you try to automate them. If you had tried to find and remove `v[1]` using a loop, before you attempted to use `find`, all of this would have been clear.

   If you want to do more subtle things, like searching by different attributes, you will have to either write the loops yourself, or learn more subtle tools like functors, `remove`  and `find_if`. Guess which one I think you should learn first.

   **EDIT:** Test iterators before you try to erase them. If you don't see why that's important, you haven't studied iterators enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do this , getter and setter functions shouldn't be like this , should be:

```
void A :: getData() // why t
{
     cout << "id = ";
     cin >> x;
     cout << "\nname = ";
     cin >> name;

}

void A :: putData()
{
cout<<"The name is :" << name <<endl;
cout<<"id is :"<<x<<endl;

}
```

In main() (you will have to declare the == operator so that you can compare the objects of user defined):

```
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
v.push_back(A());
v[i].getData();
v[i].putData();
}
vector< A >::iterator beg = v.begin(), en = v.end();
v.erase(remove(beg ,end , v[0]) , v.end());
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is not std::find, but std::find_if. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Everybody I understand what I was missing I added == operator to my class A which  is something  like :

```
bool A :: operator==(const A &t) const
{
return ( x == t.x && (strcmp(name, t.name) == 0) );
}
```

and I used my getters and setters as told by **M3taSpl0it**

It worked on the find function as far as deleting the object is concerned.